# Errors in Syslog

Tags: rhel, syslog

Im getting this error on one of the server

```
May 21 16:45:42 ERPSSO gconfd (root-24528): Failed to write "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": Failed to move temporary file "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml.new" to final location "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": No such file or directory 
May 21 16:45:42 ERPSSO gconfd (root-24528): Failed to sync one or more sources: Failed to write some configuration data to disk 
May 21 17:45:42 ERPSSO gconfd (root-24528): Failed to write "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": Failed to move temporary file "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml.new" to final location "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": No such file or directory 
May 21 17:45:42 ERPSSO gconfd (root-24528): Failed to sync one or more sources: Failed to write some configuration data to disk 
May 21 19:45:42 ERPSSO gconfd (root-24528): Failed to write "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": Failed to move temporary file "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml.new" to final location "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": No such file or directory 
May 21 19:45:42 ERPSSO gconfd (root-24528): Failed to sync one or more sources: Failed to write some configuration data to disk 
May 21 20:45:43 ERPSSO gconfd (root-24528): Failed to write "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": Failed to move temporary file "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml.new" to final location "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": No such file or directory 
May 21 20:45:43 ERPSSO gconfd (root-24528): Failed to sync one or more sources: Failed to write some configuration data to disk 
May 21 22:45:42 ERPSSO gconfd (root-24528): Failed to write "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": Failed to move temporary file "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml.new" to final location "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": No such file or directory 
May 21 22:45:42 ERPSSO gconfd (root-24528): Failed to sync one or more sources: Failed to write some configuration data to disk 
May 22 00:45:43 ERPSSO gconfd (root-23938): Failed to write "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": Failed to move temporary file "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml.new" to final location "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": No such file or directory 
May 22 00:45:43 ERPSSO gconfd (root-23938): Failed to sync one or more sources: Failed to write some configuration data to disk 
May 22 02:45:42 ERPSSO gconfd (root-23938): Failed to write "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": Failed to move temporary file "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml.new" to final location "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": No such file or directory 
May 22 02:45:42 ERPSSO gconfd (root-23938): Failed to sync one or more sources: Failed to write some configuration data to disk 
May 22 04:45:43 ERPSSO gconfd (root-23938): Failed to write "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": Failed to move temporary file "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml.new" to final location "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": No such file or directory 
May 22 04:45:43 ERPSSO gconfd (root-23938): Failed to sync one or more sources: Failed to write some configuration data to disk 
May 22 05:45:42 ERPSSO gconfd (root-23938): Failed to write "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": Failed to move temporary file "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml.new" to final location "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": No such file or directory 
May 22 05:45:42 ERPSSO gconfd (root-23938): Failed to sync one or more sources: Failed to write some configuration data to disk 
May 22 06:45:42 ERPSSO gconfd (root-23938): Failed to write "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": Failed to move temporary file "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml.new" to final location "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": No such file or directory 
May 22 06:45:42 ERPSSO gconfd (root-23938): Failed to sync one or more sources: Failed to write some configuration data to disk 
May 22 07:45:43 ERPSSO gconfd (root-23938): Failed to write "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": Failed to move temporary file "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml.new" to final location "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": No such file or directory 
May 22 07:45:43 ERPSSO gconfd (root-23938): Failed to sync one or more sources: Failed to write some configuration data to disk 
May 22 09:45:43 ERPSSO gconfd (root-23938): Failed to write "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": Failed to move temporary file "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml.new" to final location "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": No such file or directory 
May 22 09:45:43 ERPSSO gconfd (root-23938): Failed to sync one or more sources: Failed to write some configuration data to disk 
May 22 10:45:43 ERPSSO gconfd (root-23938): Failed to write "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": Failed to move temporary file "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml.new" to final location "/root/.gconf/apps/puplet/%gconf.xml": No such file or directory 
May 22 10:45:43 ERPSSO gconfd (root-23938): Failed to sync one or more sources: Failed to write some configuration data to disk 
May 22 11:37:05 ERPSSO gconfd (root-7876): starting (version 2.14.0), pid 7876 user 'root'
May 22 11:37:05 ERPSSO gconfd (root-7876): Resolved address "xml:readonly:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory" to a read-only configuration source at position 0
May 22 11:37:05 ERPSSO gconfd (root-7876): Resolved address "xml:readwrite:/root/.gconf" to a writable configuration source at position 1
May 22 11:37:05 ERPSSO gconfd (root-7876): Resolved address "xml:readonly:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.defaults" to a read-only configuration source at position 2
```

There is enough space on root /boot/and other partitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be about disk space, but about files that are supposed to exist and aren't there. So check for the existence of the files mentioned in the log.